# How to sync one menu item into other menus?

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I have a Drupal menu called Top-Nav which I use for my Top Navigation with the following 6 menu items(for example)

```
Home   a    b    c    d    e
```

Each of a, b, c, d and e have sub items.
I also have 5 other menus let's say named "menu1", "menu2", "menu3", "menu4", "menu5" that have exactly the same structure/items as a, b, c, d, e
Like "menu1" is the same as "a", "menu2" is the same as "b" ...

What I am trying to achieve is the following:
When the admin adds a new item to "a" section of Top-Nav i want to replicated that item in "menu1" programmatically, I want to sync them once the new link is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` to add a custom submit handler. In that submit handler, you will get the current menu item values. Use those values to create a new menu item for the other menu.

Functions to use:

1. [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). Here form id will be 'menu_edit_item'
2. Use form['#submit'][] = "custom submit handler" in form alter.
3. Use [menu_link_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) in custom submit handler based on the values you get form the form_state.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [hook_menu_link_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_insert/7) in a custom module.

> This hook is used to notify modules that menu items have been created.
>   Contributed modules may use the information to perform actions based
>   on the information entered into the menu system.
>
> Parameters
>
> $link: Associative array defining a menu link as passed into menu_link_save().

I make a test and it's works fine.